# find max , min of values in multidimensional dict

Tags: python, dictionary

```
stats = {{'node100': {'load_1min': '0.58'}, 'node200': {'load_1min': '0.64'}, 'node28': {'load_1min': '0.69'}}
```

I want to find
1. key with max Load_1min value ,
2. key with min Load_1min value ,
3. avg value of all the load_min keys for stats.

Last one is simple - But 1st two are tough.
I tried 
    max function but failed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `key` argument to `min` and `max`:

```
>>> min(stats, key=lambda k:float(stats[k]['load_1min']))
'node100'
>>> max(stats, key=lambda k:float(stats[k]['load_1min']))
'node28'
```

In addition to iterating over the keys, this looks up every key in the dictionary. To avoid the extra lookups:

```
>>> min(stats.items(), key=lambda (k,v):float(v['load_1min']))
('node100', {'load_1min': '0.58'})
>>> max(stats.items(), key=lambda (k,v):float(v['load_1min']))
('node28', {'load_1min': '0.69'})
```

Comment: And for average: `sum(float(x['load_1min']) for x in stats.values())/ len(stats)`

Comment: Great answer, but uncertain about the desired condition if multiple keys have the same value. One drawback is that this will only return one (effectively random) key with the maximum/minimum value if this the the case.

Comment: Thanks .. That was simply elegant.

Answer (score 3):

Since python lists are inherently unordered, and your numbers happen to be strings you have to jump through a couple hoops to do this properly, but it's not too bad.

First construct a list containing all of the values for `load_1min`, where the values are cast to floats rather than strings:

```
all_values = [float(value['load_1min']) for value in stats.values()]
```

Finding the `min` and `max`, and `average` is the pretty straightforward:

```
minimum = min(all_values)
max = max(all_values)
average = sum(all_values)/len(all_values)
```

The look again for the keys that actually match this:

```
max_key = [key for key, value in stats.items() if value['load_1min'] == max]
```

the repetition for the minimum is pretty straightforward.

Use this if you find it more understandable, but to be honest NPE's answer is more elegant. Didn't even know about the `key` argument myself.

Comment: Actually, you answer is more efficient, because in NPE's the iteration/conversion happens twice. Besides, only _values()_ are needed using _items()_ seems redundant.

Comment: @volcano May be marginally more efficient, but `(elegance + readability) > efficiency` in my book.

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/1287834/slater-tyranus If you have huge block of data, efficiency becomes an issue. Your solution may look a little bit cruder, but it is still robust and readable (and lambda may be additional burden on performance)

Comment: By the way, `stats` is a list. So `value in stats.values()` will result in an error.

Comment: @aIKid `stats` is not a `list`... It's technically a `set` with one value, which will error in and of itself since you can't store a `dict` in a `set`. Made the assumption that the extra curly brackets were an obvious typo. Not sure where you got the `list` thing from.

Comment: Oh whoops. My bad. Yes. It's a set, sorry

Answer (score 0):

```
stats = {'node100': {'load_1min': '0.58'}, 'node200': {'load_1min': '0.64'}, 'node28': {'load_1min': '0.69'}}
alist=[[float(value2) for item2, value2 in value.items()] for key,value in stats.items()]
results_val=(min(alist),max(alist))
print(results_val)
```

output:

```
Min,     Max
([0.58], [0.69])
```